# What is the most performant way to make the results of a cached computation thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

(Apologies if this was answered elsewhere; it seems like it would be a common problem, but it turns out to be hard to search for since terms like "threading" and "cache" produce overwhelming results.)

I have an expensive computation whose result is accessed frequently but changes infrequently. Thus, I cache the resulting value. Here's some c# pseudocode of what I mean:

```
int? _cachedResult = null;

int GetComputationResult()
{
    if(_cachedResult == null)
    {
        // Do the expensive computation.
        _cachedResult = /* Result of expensive computation. */;
    }
    return _cachedResult.Value;
}
```

Elsewhere in my code, I will occasionally set `_cachedResult` back to null because the input to the computation has changed and thus the cached result is no longer valid and needs to be re-computed. (Which means I can't use `Lazy<T>` since `Lazy<T>` doesn't support being reset.)

This works fine for single-threaded scenarios, but of course it's not at all thread-safe. So my question is: What is the most performant way to make `GetComputationResult` thread-safe?

Obviously I could just put the whole thing in a lock() block, but I suspect there might be a better way? (Something that would do an atomic check to see if the result needs to be recomputed and only lock if it does?)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How bad is it for threads to get stale values occasionally?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when one thread is computing and another thread wants to get the result? Should it wait or obtain the old value?

Comment: How much time does it take for the computation approximately?

Comment: `Lazy<T>` can't be reset, but you could use `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized` instead. Just set it to null when you want it to get initialized again. Although you'll have to use a wrapper reference type here instead of a nullable.

Comment: Just, FYI LazyInitializer might call the initializer multiple times but a single value will get stored in the field.

Comment: @YacoubMassad It should wait.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Depends on what you mean by stale. If the cached result is cleared during the call to GetComputationResult, then it's okay if GetComputationResult returns the value as it was when it was called.

Comment: @YacoubMassad The computation takes a few milliseconds, but the number of times its result is accessed is about 1000 for every time it actually needs to be re-computed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the double-checked locking pattern:

```
// Thread-safe (uses double-checked locking pattern for performance)
public class Memoized<T>
{
    Func<T> _compute;
    volatile bool _cached;
    volatile bool _startedCaching;
    volatile StrongBox<T> _cachedResult;  // Need reference type
    object _cacheSyncRoot = new object();

    public Memoized(Func<T> compute)
    {
        _compute = compute;
    }

    public T Value {
        get {
            if (_cached)    // Fast path
                return _cachedResult.Value;
            lock (_cacheSyncRoot)
            {
                if (!_cached)
                {
                    _startedCaching = true;
                    _cachedResult = new StrongBox<T>(_compute());
                    _cached = true;
                }
            }
            return _cachedResult.Value;
        }
    }

    public void Invalidate()
    {
        if (!_startedCaching)
        {
            // Fast path: already invalidated
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();  // need to release
            if (!_startedCaching)
                return;
        }
        lock (_cacheSyncRoot)
            _cached = _startedCaching = false;
    }
}
```

This particular implementation matches your description of what it should do in corner cases: If the cache has been invalidated, the value should only be computed once, by a single thread, and other threads should wait. However, if the cache is invalidated concurrently with the cached value being accessed, the stale cached value may be returned.

Comment: I think `_cachedResult` must be volatile and you can't reassign it's member because that reassignment is not atomic. Need a fresh instance.

Comment: And the first if and return are not atomic in combination. Might return a stale value.

Comment: @usr: _cachedResult contains a volatile field. It's atomic for most builtin types, though not all value types. Fixing, thanks! The possibility of returning a stale value under contention is on purpose, see my update.

Comment: Thank you, this is very much the kind of solution I'm looking for!

Comment: @Walt: You're welcome :-) I added in a general wrapper class for convenience with my last edit.

Comment: @Cameron Just to clarify, you're using StrongBox simply because you need a reference type wrapper (in the case that T is a value type that can't be read/modified atomically). Any reference-typed wrapper will do; there's nothing special about StrongBox in particular, right?

Comment: @WaltD: That's exactly right. It's only needed if T is a non-atomic value type, like a struct or something. I only used `StrongBox` because it already exists (handy for times like these).

Comment: @Cameron Do you really need `volatile` here since you're already locking?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you lock in `Invalidate()`? I'm not seeing any possible scenario in which it matters: if two threads run `Invalidate()` in parallel, that would still work. If one thread gets `Value` while another runs `Invalidate()`, I'm not seeing any point at which the spontaneous reset of `_cached` might cause problems during the execution of the `Value` getter.

Comment: @Asad: Yes, I need both the flag and value to be volatile since they are both accessed outside of the lock (as well as in it). If they weren't, the JITter would be allowed to do unsafe optimizations, and the memory ordering guarantees would also not be correct in the fast path.

Comment: @hvd: I lock to invalidate because otherwise a thread could invalidate the cache a second time *just* after the computation was done, but before the thread that did the computation sets `_cached` to true, leading to the invalidation being lost. It's not completely ideal, I'll add a fast path to `Invalidate` too.

Comment: @Cameron True, but if `Invalidate()` and the `Value` getter are run in parallel, the user is already not able to predict whether the `_cached` flag will be cleared once both methods return, even with the locking. :) `Invalidate()` could just as well have cleared the flag just before the `Value` getter acquired the lock.

Comment: @hvd: Ah, but the thread calling `Invalidate()` may have changed some state that affects the result of a new computation. If the value is being computed in parallel with `Invalidate()`, then we want the value obtained *after* the call to `Invalidate()` completes to always be based off the new state. Which makes me realize I'm missing a memory barrier. Editing...

Comment: @Cameron can you please explain why you added that memory barrier? I Don't understand.

Comment: @Walt: If someone changes global state affecting the result of the computation, then calls `Invalidate()`, the implied guarantee is that anyone who obtains the value after `Invalidate()` has *completely returned* will get a value at least as recent. In order for that to happen, `Invalidate()` has to ensure that its state changes are visible to the other threads at the point when the new value is next being computed, which makes the barrier necessary (the locks have implicit full barriers on entry/exit).

Comment: @Walt: An example: If a thread changes state then calls invalidate while the value is being computed, the computed value may be based on stale data, and the resulting cached value will not be recalculated despite the call to invalidate because it will have been put up to date. Which makes me realize, the memory barrier doesn't help this at all; what we really need is a variable to tell us the value has started to be computed. Fixing...

Comment: volatile always reminds me:  Timeo Danaos et dona ferentes  :). volatile is a pretty dangerous construct, better to leave it be, the sleeping beast:)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this will provide some food for thought:).

1. Generic class.
2. The class can compute data asynchronously or synchronously.
3. Allows fast reads thanks to the spinlock.
4. Does not perform heavy stuff inside the spinlock, just returning Task and if necessary, creating and starting Task on default TaskScheduler, to avoid inlining.

Task with Spinlock is pretty powerful combination, that can solve some problems in lock-free way.

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Example
    {
        class OftenReadSometimesUpdate<T>
        {
            private Task<T> result_task = null;
            private SpinLock spin_lock = new SpinLock(false);
            private TResult LockedFunc<TResult>(Func<TResult> locked_func)
            {
                TResult t_result = default(TResult);
                bool gotLock = false;
                if (locked_func == null) return t_result;

                try
                {
                    spin_lock.Enter(ref gotLock);
                    t_result = locked_func();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (gotLock) spin_lock.Exit();
                    gotLock = false;
                }
                return t_result;
            }


            public Task<T> GetComputationAsync()
            {
                return
                LockedFunc(GetComputationTaskLocked)
                ;
            }
            public T GetComputationResult()
            {
                return
                LockedFunc(GetComputationTaskLocked)
                .Result
                ;
            }
            public OftenReadSometimesUpdate<T> InvalidateComputationResult()
            {
                return
                this
                .LockedFunc(InvalidateComputationResultLocked)
                ;
            }
            public OftenReadSometimesUpdate<T> InvalidateComputationResultLocked()
            {
                result_task = null;
                return this;
            }

            private Task<T> GetComputationTaskLocked()
            {
                if (result_task == null)
                {
                    result_task = new Task<T>(HeavyComputation);
                    result_task.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
                }
                return result_task;
            }
            protected virtual T HeavyComputation()
            {
                //a heavy computation
                return default(T);//return some result of computation
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply reassign the `Lazy<T>` to achieve a reset:

```
Lazy<int> lazyResult = new Lazy<int>(GetComputationResult);

public int Result { get { return lazyResult.Value; } }

public void Reset()
{
   lazyResult = new Lazy<int>(GetComputationResult);
}
```